# Youtube Google API V3: List Videos not returning video tags

Tags: tags, youtube-api, meta-tags, youtube-data-api

I am currently trying to get the tags of a youtube video using the Google API V3. I am authenticating my business account and querying for videos we have uploaded through that account. I am not seeing tags for the videos I am querying for. (Yes, they do have tags applied to them)

When I authenticate with my personal account, and query videos that I have personally uploaded, I am able to see the tags for those videos.

Both accounts have the Youtube Data API enabled under the https://console.developers.google.com project.

Is there somthing more I need to do in order to get the tags I am looking for on my business account?

I am even seeing the same results when using the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) on the Google Developers API Reference

Any information on why this could be happening is appreciated! TYIA!

Comment: Is your business account a completely separate GMail (or Google Apps for Business) account, or is it just a different YouTube account linked to a Google+ page?

Answer (score 0):

You should add onBehalfofContentOwner parameter to your request to show yourself as the content owner, so the tags of your videos show up.