# Can't upload or update video with tags

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm uploading the video through my app using the documented PHP API library with pretty much the same code as here; https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#updating_a_video_by_adding_new_tags.

The uploaded video receives the title, description and playlist correctly, but not the tags.

Any clues at all?

Edit: 
I'm wondering if it has anything to do with scope, does it matter if i've authorized with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`?

This question: [Youtube Google API V3: List Videos not returning video tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695927/youtube-google-api-v3-list-videos-not-returning-video-tags?rq=1)
gets an answer suggesting the "onBehalfOfContentOwner" parameter, however, i'm getting `"HTTP 403: youtube.common, Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized"` when trying to upload with that parameter (`$insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert('status,snippet', $video, ['onBehalfOfContentOwner' => true]);`)

Comment: Given you've provided no useful information (e.g. actual code), I'm going to call PEBKAC as the cause...

Comment: I thought it unnecessary as it's basically example code with obvious variables switched out

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, not sure why it is a problem though; when setting the tags i was doing an array filter, when i removed that as a desperate test or "am i blind and using the wrong array_* function", the tags came through

So changing

```
$snippet->setTags(array_filter($medium['properties']['keywords']));
```

to

```
$snippet->setTags($medium['properties']['keywords']);
```

did the trick... I could reproduce the problem by re-adding the array_filter, and i made sure to check so it wasn't actually empty,

```
var_dump(array_filter($medium['properties']['keywords']), $medium['properties']['keywords']);
```

yielded the same result